# Clear BadgeNotification on Windows 8.1 Phone when starting app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm trying to remove a BadgeNotification from the notification panel. clicking on it let it disappear and opening my app, but I want to clear all pending badge motifications when opening my app.

Tried the following:

```
Windows.UI.Notifications.BadgeUpdateManager.createBadgeUpdaterForApplication().clear();
```

This returns undefined and will not dismiss the badge notifications.

They are acessible via

```
Windows.UI.Notifications.BadgeUpdateManager.getTemplateContent(0).getElementsByTagName("badge")
```

Is there any way to dismiss them?

Thanks in advance!